# Where to store global data in angular js ? "application controller"

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In angular JS. I am trying to make a controller on a body tag that have global user information like user name that should be displayed in different views.

Her i call the controller over body tag before ng-view.

```
    <div class="main-container ">
    <!--alert Message-->
        <div flash-alert  class="col-4 alert  fnone pt10">
            <div >
                <span href="" class="close-btn" ng-click="hide()"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
                <strong class="alert-heading">{{flash.type | uppercase}}:</strong>
                <span class="alert-message">{{flash.message}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <section class="top-header dark-blue col-10 p40">
            <div class="logo col-1 fnone">
                Corpmeter
            </div>
            <ul class=" pull-right top-links">
                <li class="alert-btn"><a href="">Report</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Contact us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </section>



    </div> <!-- Main Container -->
    <ng-view></ng-view>


</body> <!-- End Body -->
```

Her is the controller that suppose to get user data from a factory called Session.

```
(function(){
angular.module("AccApp").controller('UserController', [ '$scope', 'Session', function($scope, Session) {
    alert("Hi");
}]);

})();
```

That factory "Session" has object user which contines information about user get instantiated by another factory when the user is successfully loges in  before that the object is null. The problem is UserController runs before log in happen it runs automatically so the session is null any ideas how can i make that controller waits for the factory to gets instantiated. OR where should i save user information that navigate with every page. I do not want to store them on the global root scoop.

Comment: Store the user information in a service and inject it where ever required.

Comment: however i will inject the service in every route controller. which i feel it is not correct!

Comment: @MohamedAbbas, did you find a solution to your issue?